# Using raspberry pi to read a 16 bit ADC?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, adc

I am trying to read in an ADC (16 bit ADS1115) to my Raspberry Pi using Python.

My concern is that I have looked high and low and have not been able to find any help for the code.

How can I create a function in Python in order for my Raspberry Pi to be able to read the ADS1115?

Comment: It looks like the Pi has [built in code to do this](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ads1x15_ex_singleended.py)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the ADC, I forked Adafruit's library a while back to enable you to install it like a library..can be found [here](https://github.com/dhhagan/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code). Just install it from the git repo (download or clone the repo) and then run `setup.py`.

You can then import like any other library:

```
from ADS1115 import ADS1115

adc = ADS1115(address)
adc.readADCSingleEnded(channelNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solely use vanilla Raspian Python libraries described on my homepage https://smartypies.com/projects/ads1115-with-raspberrypi-and-python/ with sample code and circuit for 4 different use cases. Among others, as a watchdog when the value leaves a certain range an alert is triggered. Hope it helps.